# Object is null set in Defalut add Card in Arraylist

Tags: java, android

I create Default class with see list Cart in all app

```
 public class Default extends Application {

 public ArrayList<Card> listCard;

        public ArrayList<Card> getListCard() {
            return listCard;
        }

        public void setListCard(ArrayList<Card> listCard) {
            this.listCard = listCard;
        }

    }
```

Next when

```
public class ScanQrCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private ArrayList<Card> cardList;
```

....

```
                    if (hotpValue.equals(passwordHotp)) {

                        Card card = new Card(path3, base32, nameCard, intervalTotp, passwordHotp, getDate(), expirationDate, hotpValue);

                      Default app = (Default) getApplicationContext();
                            cardList = app.getListCard();
                            cardList.add(card); // show error line code 
                            app.setListCard(cardList);
                            cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
                            cardList= app.getListCard();
                            System.out.println("Dodanokarte"+card.getNameCard());

                    }
```

see log

> Process: com.novum.smrtkarta, PID: 13844
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                            at
>   com.xxxx.smrtkarta.activity.ScanQrCodeActivity$3$1.run(ScanQrCodeActivity.java:277)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

What I do wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work you have to change
Change:

```
ArrayList<Card> listCard
```

to:

```
ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>;
```

Comment: change this line in class Defult ?

Answer (score 2):

Here `cardList` is null. Make sure that you have initialized the `listCard` in `Default` class before calling `getListCard` method